# Start file in call block

Tags: batch-file

I made a script named `Start_in_call.bat`

```
@echo off
title Start in Call
echo Start Script
echo Parameters : [%0 %1 %2]
call :label1
echo End of Script
pause
exit

:label1
echo Start of Label1
echo Parameters : [%0 %1 %2]
pause
Start_in_call.bat rem qwe
echo End of Label1
goto :EOF
```

I expect the script to open itself with `rem qwe` as the parameter 
I ran the file and this is the output:

```
Start Script
Parameters : ["S:\alot\of\folders\Start_in_call.bat"]

Start of Label1
Parameters : [:label1  ]
Press any key to continue . . .
Start of Label1
Parameters : [Start_in_call.bat rem qwe]
Press any key to continue . . .
Start of Label1
Parameters : [Start_in_call.bat rem qwe]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I noticed that the script do some kind of `goto label1` instead of opening itself
Anyone know how did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a `call` command, a new *"batch context"* is created, the code in the batch file readed and if it is determined that the context has been created by a `call :label` a implicit `goto :label` is executed.

Now, from inside the subroutine you directly invoke a batch file (doesn't matter if the same or other batch file) but without using the `call` command. This creates a batch context that *replaces* the current context but does not clear the previous `call :label` situation. This leads to a new implicit `goto :label`

This is used to implement a "library of functions" (you can see a working sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30170342/2861476))

Change your `Start_in_call.bat` to `call Start_in_call.bat`.