# Why CALL prints the GOTO help message in this script?And why command after that are executed twice?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

[Here's one interesting thread](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=20360). And I tried to play with the two things discussed there.

1. You can access labels with special symbols with double expansion.
2. Labels that contain `/?` cannot be used because `GOTO` and `CALL` prints their help messages instead of execution.

And here's the result:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "label=/?"

    call :%%label%%
    echo == Test message to check if the CALL or GOTO ( or neither ) command is executed  ==

exit /b 0

:/?
    echo == CALL or GOTO has been executed ==
exit /b 0
```

And the output:

```
Directs cmd.exe to a labeled line in a batch program.

GOTO label

  label   Specifies a text string used in the batch program as a label.

You type a label on a line by itself, beginning with a colon.

If Command Extensions are enabled GOTO changes as follows:

GOTO command now accepts a target label of :EOF which transfers control
to the end of the current batch script file.  This is an easy way to
exit a batch script file without defining a label.  Type CALL /?  for a
description of extensions to the CALL command that make this feature
useful.
== Test message to check if the CALL or GOTO ( or neither ) command is executed  ==
== Test message to check if the CALL or GOTO ( or neither ) command is executed  ==
```

And the code after the `CALL` is executed twice??

**EDIT**

This is even more unexplainable to me:

```
@echo off

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "label=/?"
    set /a x=1
    call :%%label%% >nul

    set /a x=x+1
    echo ---
    echo -%x%-
    echo ---

exit /b 0

:/?
    echo == CALL or GOTO has been executed ==
    echo == first argument : %1 ==
exit /b 0
```

The output is:

```
---
-3-
---
```

The code after the call of the `CALL` for sure is executed twice, but the output of the first run can be redirected in the same line?

Comment: What makes this even more perplexing (if that is possible) is if you add a `& pause` after the `call` it echo's everything once, pauses and than echoes it **after** the pause!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm always surprised, that you still found things that never came to my mind to test.

Contrary to Aacini, I don't believe that `:/?` acts here as a valid label.
Else this should find such a label.

I suppose that the `CALL` command is internally composed of a stack pusher function and then just use `GOTO` to jump to the label.

And as you are using late expansion the `/?` isn't detected by the `CALL` command itself, but by the `GOTO` command.
The `goto` shows only the help info and finished, but as the `call` has already pushed the fileposition to the stack it works like calling this filepostion and later return to the same location!

```
set "help=^ /?"
call :myLabel%%help%%
```

This shows also the help, like a `GOTO :myLabel /?` would do.
But this one don't

```
set "help=/?"
call :myLabel %%help%%
```

I suppose, the GOTO gets only the label parsed by the CALL, the other parameters are moved to `%1, %2, ...`

And this could explain why only the **label can use delayed expansion two times**.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "label=myLabel"
set "pointer=^!label^!"
call :!pointer!
exit /b

:myLabel
echo it works
```

Comment: Right. The `call` command followed by a colon starts the generation of a new batch context. The batch code is loaded into this context and, if the element that generated the context starts with a colon it is considered a label and a `goto` is executed to jump to this label. It was used and indicated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30170342/2861476). Just as a curiosity, there is a internal variable defined just to hide the `goto` execution when `echo` is enabled.

Comment: Sound like the answer! First thing that came to my mind was - Is it possible to force a `call :eof` to jump to the end of file like the `goto`.btw most of the internal commands prints their help no matter where the string `?` is placed in the arguments.But only `rem` has a problems with double expansion here : `set "h=/?"&call rem  %%h%%`

Comment: @MCND - what internal variable?

Comment: Excuse me jeb, but I disagree. If the `call :%%label%%` command would fail, the standard response would be to show "Label not found" message and set errorlevel=1. No one of these things happen here. See the EDIT #2 in my answer...

Comment: @npocmaka, nothing accesible from batch code. Just a memory address used as a flag. I saw it when debugging `cmd` just to be sure before posting the answer linked in the previous comment.

Comment: @Aacini - but I think it's reasonable.If `CALL` uses the `GOTO` to parse the label , and then `GOTO` detects the `/?` there'll be no need of error message.

Comment: Ok. I reviewed this point and concluded that jeb is right, with one detail. He said "The goto simply fails", but no; the execution of `goto :/?` execute correctly and show the GOTO help screen. The CALL part see no error in the GOTO part, so it continue normally...

Comment: Great analysis to come up with simple rules that account for the behavior.

Comment: @Aacini Thanks, and you are right, the `goto :/?` doesn't fail, I will change the text

Answer (score 3):

Interesting! The first code may be reduced to:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "label=/?"

    call :%%label%%
    echo == Test message to check if the CALL or GOTO ( or neither ) command is executed  ==
```

and still show the same output, that is, it behaves the same way than this code:

```
@echo off

setlocal

call :/?
echo == Test message to check if the CALL or GOTO ( or neither ) command is executed  ==
```

where the `call :/?` is *both* a call command *and* a valid label, AND considering `:/?` a valid label. Wow!

Why the GOTO help is displayed? No idea!!!

**EDIT**: *Additional tests*

This code:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "label=/?"

    set i=0
    call :%%label%%  &  echo Command in same line:  i=%i%
    set /A i+=10
    echo == Test message ==     i=%i%
```

show the GOTO help screen first, and then:

```
== Test message ==     i=10
Command in same line:  i=0
== Test message ==     i=20
```

but if `EnableDelayedExpansion` is added and `%i%` is changed by `!i!` in the call line, then it shows:

```
== Test message ==     i=10
Command in same line:  i=10
== Test message ==     i=20
```

as "expected"...

**EDIT #2**

The test below show that the `call :%%label%%` command does NOT report the ERRORLEVEL=1 standard on "label not found" error:

```
@echo off

setlocal
set "label=/?"

    call :notFound
    echo Label not found: ERRROLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%
    ver > NUL
    echo Reset errorlevel: ERRROLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%

    call :%%label%%
    echo == Test message == ERRROLEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL%
```