# How to pass switch `/?` over to a sub-routine without being processed by `call`?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, escaping, call

Supposing you have the following code snippet:

```
@echo off
call :SUB /?
exit /B

:SUB
>&2 echo %*
exit /B
```

The `call` command recognises the `/?` switch and displays its help message. How can I pass that argument over to the sub-routine, so that it is only processed there but not by the `call` command? Is there a clever escape sequence to accomplish that?

So far I tried some escape sequences like `call :SUB ^/?`, `call :SUB /^?`, `call :SUB ^/^?`, `call :SUB^ /?`, and also the odd syntax `call :SUB(/?` (which does not throw a syntax error surprisingly; similar to the widely used syntax for safe `echo(`), but no luck so far.

In the command prompt, the same problem arises when writing something like `call echo /?`.

Comment: `call :SUB "/?"`, if you can live with the quotes or can use `%~1` in your subroutine.

Comment: Good idea, @Stephan, but this works only if `/?` is the only argument...

Comment: that's why it's a comment, not an answer. `;)`

Comment: _this works only if /? is the only argument._ It depends on your subroutine. If you want to echo all args, it will. But if you want to echo each arg separately, it will too, like: `set "ars= %*" & echo %~1 !ars: %~1=!`

Comment: @sambul35, I used `echo` in the sub-routine just as an example; the problem is that `call` consumes the `/?` on its own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is very greedy, even this will display the help screen

```
call :sub ^/;;===,,,,,?
```

But it can be done with a helper variable.

```
@echo off
set "var=/?"
call :sub %%var%%
exit /B

:sub
echo(Parameter: %*
exit /b
```

**Additional info**:
When the `/?` is used as a label there are other strange effects, then the `/?` can be used for [*anonymous* functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31987023/463115).

```
@echo off
set "anonymous=/?"
call :%%anonymous%% argument >nul
if "%0"==":/?" (
  echo func arg=%1 > con
  exit /b
)
echo End
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I pass that argument over to the sub-routine, so that it is only processed there but not by the call command?

See the example below:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :SUB "/?" Hello
exit /b

:SUB
set "ars= %*"
echo %~1 & echo/ & echo !ars: %1=! 
exit /b

:: Output
Displays messages, or turns command-echoing on or off.

  ECHO [ON | OFF]
  ECHO [message]

Type ECHO without parameters to display the current echo setting.

 Hello
```