# Make a command affect another running batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

I've got two batch files which are running at the same time. Now I need to execute a command in the first batch file, but it will be executed in the second one.

For example, I want to change the color of the second batch program using the first one. If I type in the command `color 0a`, I want it to be executed in the second batch program.

The batch pseudo code would be like this

```
execute "goto :a" in "example.bat"
```

Is this possible?

*By the way, I cannot hardcode this stuff and I'm not advanced so if you can please briefly explain what I have to do.*

Comment: see the [MCND](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2861476/mc-nd)'s answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30168091/call-a-subroutine-in-a-batch-from-another-batch-file)

Comment: Are you trying to call into the second batch file like a library of subroutines or are you trying to influence the execution of the console process running the second script?

Comment: Influence the execution of the console process running the second script. Exactly as you said. Pseudo batch code would be like
`execute "goto a" in "process2.bat"`

Comment: By the way, i dont understand that much of batch, so MCND's answer is very very unclear to me. i don't understand a single word